# PHPUnit and Symfony2 Cannot access global variables

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, dbunit

Here is my phpunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         processIsolation="false"
         colors="true"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="./" />
        <var name="DB_DSN" value="mysql:dbname=test_xxx;host=localhost" />
        <var name="DB_USER" value="root" />
        <var name="DB_PASSWD" value="" />
        <var name="DB_DBNAME" value="test_xxx" /> 
    </php>


    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage" title="App Code Coverage" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
        lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

In my:

- src

  - AppBundle

    - Tests

      - AbstractDatabaseTestCase.php

AbstractDatabaseTestCase.php:

```
abstract class AbstractDatabaseTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase{

    /**
     * 
     *@var PDO 
     * 
     */
    static $pdo;

    /**
     * 
     *@var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection description 
     * 
     */
    static $dbal;

    private $conn;

    final public function getConnection()
    {
        var_dump($GLOBALS);
 // here my GLOBALS['DB_DSN'], GLOBALS['DB_USER'], GLOBALS['DB_PASSWD'] are not seen.

        if ($this->conn === null) {
            if (self::$pdo == null) {
                self::$pdo = new \PDO( $GLOBALS['DB_DSN'], $GLOBALS['DB_USER'], $GLOBALS['DB_PASSWD'] );
            }
            $this->conn = $this->createDefaultDBConnection(self::$pdo, $GLOBALS['DB_DBNAME']);
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
```

As you can see from the comments, given the fact that I followed the documentation, my class doesn't seem to see the globals defined in the phpunit.xml file.

Do you have any ideas? Have I missed something?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked $_SERVER?

Comment: @RenatoMendesFigueiredo It did the same to all the variables, now given that it led me to the answer below, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In symfony2, the default phpunit.xml is not the one in app/phpunit.xml but in the root of the application. Put all the values there and everything worked fine.